# Parsing JSON Array in Recyclerview using volley, why it show less data than it have on server?

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley

i am trying to parse `Json Array` in `recyclerview` using `volley` in `android`, but it show less data than it have on server.
i mean it parse only 4 data, server have 10. why?
code:

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,

```
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {                
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                       JSONObject data, deal_mode;
    String total, ref, name,category_name,start_date,end_date,offer_price,market_price,gain,structure_note,other_note;

    data = resp.getJSONObject("data");
    total = data.getString("total");
    JSONArray data1 = data.getJSONArray("data");

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i <response.length(); i++) {           
            JSONObject jresponse = data1.getJSONObject(i);
            ref = jresponse.getString("ref");
            name = jresponse.getString("name");
            deal_mode = jresponse.getJSONObject("deal_mode");
            category_name=deal_mode.getString("category_name");
            start_date=jresponse.getString("start_date");
            end_date=jresponse.getString("end_date");
            offer_price=jresponse.getString("offer_price");
            market_price=jresponse.getString("market_price");
            gain=jresponse.getString("gain");
            structure_note=jresponse.getString("structure_note");
            other_note=jresponse.getString("other_note");

            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          
        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }) {
        //This is for Headers
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            params.put("Authorization", "Bearer" + getToken);
            return params;
        }
    };
    //Add the Request to the RequestQueue.
    VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectReq, REQUEST_TAG);
```

Comment: where is your code...???

Comment: Dinesh please post your code for better reference

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
    for (int i = 0; i <data1.length(); i++) {           
        JSONObject jresponse = data1.getJSONObject(i);
        ref = jresponse.getString("ref");
        name = jresponse.getString("name");
        deal_mode = jresponse.getJSONObject("deal_mode");
        category_name=deal_mode.getString("category_name");
        start_date=jresponse.getString("start_date");
        end_date=jresponse.getString("end_date");
        offer_price=jresponse.getString("offer_price");
        market_price=jresponse.getString("market_price");
        gain=jresponse.getString("gain");
        structure_note=jresponse.getString("structure_note");
        other_note=jresponse.getString("other_note");

        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();          
    }
```

The error in your code is that you are only iterating your for loop to response.length but the for loop should iterate to data1.length array.
Problem Solved Cheers !!!

Comment: There might be some error please look into the stacktrace and paste the parsing code and link to the sample json. Then i can help you better.

Comment: now my next data is on next page, i mean 10 data per page. i parse that in recyclerview, how i parse next data to my recyclerview when we scroll down the recyclerview?

Comment: Please upvote the answer so that it could help others looking for it.

Comment: for this you can use pagination in recyclerview this link would help you out.
https://medium.com/@etiennelawlor/pagination-with-recyclerview-1cb7e66a502b